# keystore file without password of account can be a problem?

Tags: mist, wallets, security, password

In mist you create an account and you provide password. Now your keystore files have been accessed by unauthorized people but not your password which is in your head and only there. Can your ethers be stolen using only those files?

Answer (score 1):

"Unlocking" you wallet if someone can have access to your wallet file depends of your password strength.
If you really want to store all your assets in this wallet, please, keep your wallet files and password safe on an encrypted offline computer or use a hardware wallet like Ledger nano s or Trezor.
Trust no one.

Comment: If your password is safe but easy enough to be brute forced, your ether is at risk. Anyway if you have any doubt, simply create another wallet (simple address or multi-sig contract) and move all you funds, the old compromised account will still be at risk but with a zero balance so you can abandon it.

Comment: No, you can prepare you transaction offline( https://myetherwallet.groovehq.com/knowledge_base/topics/how-do-i-make-an-offline-transaction), using an offline version of MyEtherWallet (download it on the github page https://github.com/MyEtherWallet/MyEtherWallet) and then transfer it using an usb key to your online computer to include it in the live chain.

Comment: I think you really don't understand what an Ethereum address is, no offense, but just please read something like that https://myetherwallet.groovehq.com/knowledge_base/topics/0-im-new-what-do-i-do

Comment: What do you mean? Generating an address is a fully offline process using only cryptography process.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your passport is safe, it can be guessed by simply trying all the possible passwords. For your password to be secure, it has not only to be long, but to be somehow random. `qwerty` or `password` can be guessed easily. If you use real words, you have to use several of them, chosen randomly. To learn more, you can search "entropy in information theory".

It is always easier to attack your password than your secret key, so you should really pay attention to get it secure.

Any password an be guessed, but the cost becomes exponentially higher with entropy (i.e. "randomness + length").